# using python to loading from txt to db2,but failed.Why?

Tags: python, db2

I want to load file(.txt) to db2 database,using db2 connect to MyDB and load from myfile.txt del insert into Schema.MyTable >> myfile.txt.log.I use python to automate this job. The code like belows.

```
for s in  os.listdir(os.chdir("/home/db2inst1/preDB/201701/")):
    print(os.getcwd())
    try:
       ........
       os.system(cntdb2)#cntdb2= db2 connect to MyDB2
       os.system(loadcmd)#loadcmd= db2 load from 'myfile.txt' of del insert into "Schema"."MyTable" >>"myfile.txt.log"

    except exception as e:
       print("Failed to read this file!")
       print(e)
```

But I got a message that 
       SQL1024N  A database connection does not exist.  SQLSTATE=08003
When I execute the command 
       db2 connect to MyDB2 
       db2 load from from 'myfile.txt' of del insert into "Schema"."MyTable" >>"myfile.txt.log"
I can get the data loaded.

what mistakes do I make?

Comment: I got it.the os.system Execute the command (a string) in a subshell. This is implemented by calling the Standard C function system(), and has the same limitations...so, I need to add && or ; to combine the two command.

Comment: Note: If you set the environment variable `DB2DBDFT` to the name of your database, DB2 will make an implicit connection, eliminating the need to issue the `connect to ...` statement.

Answer (score 0):

To run both commands at once, you can put them into a text file:

```
connect to MyDB2
load from 'myfile.txt' ...
```

and execute them with

```
os.system('db2 -f /path/to/script.file')
```